# Facebook thumbnails

Tags: php, facebook, image, thumbnails

i have a simple script, that outputs image to browser, like this:

```
Header("Content-type: image/webp");
header('X-Sendfile: ' . $href);

imagejpeg($image, null, 100);
imagejpeg($image, null, 100);
```

But when i put this link to facebook, its not detected as image.
Link example:
https://teststore0.cloud-dev.soborka.net/getimg/de4368f84cc97dcf100d8d21730fa1e6.jpg
its rewrites by htaccess to php script

Comment: is it because you're serving it via https with invalid certificate?

Comment: @MicJaw yeah, you were right. Post it as answer, and i will choose it